# Unable to assign object retrieved from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, protocols

For some reason I am unable to assign an object which I retrieve from a mutable array

**UPDATE: Note that I'm using ARC**

Here is the code:

```
id<Control> control = [formControlUtils getControlWithId:@"123"];
// Here control.controlValue is "Old value"
control.controlValue = @"New value";
// Even after assigning a new value to the property the value is still "Old value"

- (id<Control>)getControlWithId:(NSString *)controlId {
id<Control> control = nil;

for (NSArray *array in [FormRenderManager sharedInstance].formControls)
{
    //[FormRenderManager sharedInstance].formControls is a mutable array, so is the nested arrays
    control = [[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"controlId = %@", controlId]] lastObject];

    if (control)
        break;
}

return control;
}
```

As you can see in my code comments above, whenever a assign a new value to control.controlValue the old value still persists.

Why is that? Do I perhaps miss something fundamental here or is it due to the fact that I work against a protocol `<id>Control control` ?

Comment: Does `[FormRenderManager sharedInstance].formControls` always return the same array, or a new autoreleased instance for each call?

Comment: I've updated my question to point out that I'm using ARC. [FormRenderManager sharedInstance].formControls will always return the same array.

Comment: thanks! Very strange in this case... I'll think about it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filteredArrayUsingPredicate` returns an immutable array. You will have to do this:

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[array filtered...]];
```